# Android Enthusiasts Top User Swag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Android Enthusiasts t-shirt in your size
- Android Enthusiasts die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: android.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: android.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: Yessssssssssssss!!!!! Finally :D

Comment: Hahaha, I like the round bot.

Comment: Shocked to find out I'm still in the top 10. But cool swag, yah? Thanks Anna (and crew).

Comment: I hope I get contacted. I'm in page 1, aren't I? :)

Comment: I have a question though. By 1st / 2nd page, do you mean in Desktop or Mobile view? Mobile view has only 20 users per page, while Desktop view has 36 users per page. Thankfully, I still fit in either criteria. :)

Comment: @geffchang Desktop view.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't realize I was in the top 50 until I looked at that page. I'm looking forward to the care package. :-)

Comment: Sweet!!! Thank you Anna :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you very much in advance for this awesome gift.

Comment: Wow, I haven't been here in ages yet I still qualify, all I can say is thanks, and expect to see more of me!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the cool stuff. I was surprised to see that I'm in the top two pages.

Comment: Thats awesome...never expected anything like this..thank God I'm in 2nd page...

Comment: @AnnaLear Will it take 6 weeks for shipping to US as well? P.S. You also rock :P

Comment: @roxan It's a big country. Sometimes the delivery hamsters get tired.

Comment: @AnnaLear haha, The reason I asked is my friend will be leaving USA and coming home (i.e. my country) in four weeks time. If it can get shipped before that it would be better option for me to ship to USA rather than ship to my home country Nepal where they might give unnecessary headache in custom.

Comment: @roxan Drop me an email (the address is in my profile) and we'll work this out. We can likely ship to your friend instead. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I like the shirt design, it's neat and clean :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I've emailed you yesterday :D

Comment: The "question" was posted a week ago, and I haven't received and email yet. Have you gotten around to collecting addresses yet?

Comment: @StephenSchrauger Yeah, you should've received an email on Monday. Is the address in your profile correct? I'll resend.

Comment: Yeah!! Now that's what I'm talking about!! Thanks!! <3

Comment: Anyone got it? I'm curious abt its arrival.

Comment: @MattLin it's shipping out this week.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks for the information!.....

Comment: I have just received mine today up in Canada.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Compro01 AWESOME! Could you post pics somewhere? I imagine it will take much, much longer for Philippines.

Comment: I have received item today in India... Thanks StackExchange.com

Comment: @MattLin Was it via FedEx? Or regular mail?

Comment: @geffchang sorry bro, I wasn't here when it delivered..My friends accepted it. They Don't know which courier service that was. I think its via regular mail(not sure).

Comment: Received mine in the UK this week. Thanks hugely.

Comment: Got mine as well. Thanks a lot to everybody at [SE] and [android.se]

Comment: @geffchang **[Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hS43c.jpg)** you go mate! :)

Comment: Today my package arrived. Thank you very much for your kindness!

Answer (score 7):

Just thought I'd share some pics, as some of the others have done on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/programmers-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users).

**With my Android mini-figure:**

[image]

**The whole package, minus the blue StackExchange box:**

[image]

I think the letter with Joel Spolky's sig (despite not addressed to me)
is the BEST PART of the package. **PRICELESS**.

[image]

**THANK YOU StackEchange for these goodies!**

Comment: You're very welcome. :)